# Qt5 / Eclipse / Linux Problems with conversion from Qt4 to Qt5

Tags: linux, eclipse, qt, cmake, qt5

I tried to convert a project from Qt4 to Qt5. Until now stackoverflow search and Google helped me, but now i'm stuck.

I have rewritten the cmake files and all includes to the new Qt header are placed. Also the library should be added correctly. In my eclipse project all header are found but for some objects eclipse underlines in red with following comment:

Symbol `XXX` could not be resolved

`XXX` is for example:

```
QMainWindow  
QWidget  
QGroupBox
```

other objects like `QPushButton`, `QLineEdit` are not underlined.

To be honest above the switch from Qt4 to Qt5, I switched from Win/VS10 to Linux/Eclipse.

So anyone can give me a hint ?

Would really appreciate it. 
Thanks

Edit: How I add Qt in cmake:

```
  find_package(Qt5Widgets)
  if (Qt5Widgets_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "Qt5Widgets found.")
  else (Qt5Widgets_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "Qt5Widgets not found!")
  endif (Qt5Widgets_FOUND)

  find_package(Qt5OpenGL)
  if (Qt5OpenGL_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "QtOpenGl found.")
  else (Qt5OpenGL_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "QtOpenGL not found!")
  endif (Qt5OpenGL_FOUND)
```

...

```
include_directories( ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES}  ${Qt5OpenGL_INCLUDES})
add_executable(exp_test_qtTemplate ${files} )
target_link_libraries( exp_test_qtTemplate   ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES}  ${Qt5OpenGL_LIBRARIES})
```

And this is somth strange in the qt generated moc File

```
#include <QtCore/qbytearray.h>
#include <QtCore/qmetatype.h>
#if !defined(Q_MOC_OUTPUT_REVISION)
#error "The header file 'GlViewer.h' doesn't include <QObject>."
#elif Q_MOC_OUTPUT_REVISION != 67
#error "This file was generated using the moc from 5.0.1. It"
#error "cannot be used with the include files from this version of Qt."
#error "(The moc has changed too much.)"
#endif
```

looks like a failed installation of Qt.

Comment: Is it just Eclipse underlining some words or does the actual compilation process fail?

Comment: Oh sry, forget that. The compilation process failed with a hughe amount of error. It is not the plain underlining problem some persons on stackoverflow have with eclipse.

Comment: How about telling us your first few error(s)? In your case I would create a small working example program with *QtCreator* and compare the Makefile and every compiler/linker flag. This will lead you to the cause of the problem.

Comment: Well the first ERROR is: Field MetaObject could not be resolved.(in moc Files.cpp) But actually you are right I will have to create a minimalist example for anyone to help me. I never used QtCreator but thanks for the hint. Ill try this.

Comment: Are all moc files up-to-date? Have you really regenerated everything after the switch to the new version?

Comment: It's a completly new system. All moc uptodate. I'm trieing the QtCreator and the Error messages are more simple. fatal error: QGLWidget: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: Simple Error:

if converting from qt4 to qt5 and using cmake you have to add the qt5_modules as showed here
http://www.kdab.com/using-cmake-with-qt-5./

This solves the problem  ...(Cant answer my own question so i have to use comments)